# TKInter not working when I code in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a short program that uses a flight api. For what I am trying to do, I want lines 30 to 59(where "Client" is, to right before "root.mainloop") to be inside the function flightInfo. When I have the code formatted as it is right now(see below) , the tkinter window I am using for my GUI works fine. However when I move the api code (30-59) inside the function, my TKinter window does not open. Any assistance would be appreciated! I don't see why moving the api code(30-59) messes with the tkinter window. Thank You

[Link to image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Dg7.png)

```
from duffel_api import Duffel
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def flightInfo():
    client = Duffel(access_token="token")

    destination = input("\nWhere do you want to go?\n").strip()
    origin = input("\nFrom where?\n").strip()
    departure_date = input("\nOn what date? (YYYY-MM-DD)\n").strip()

    print("\nSearching flights...")

    slices = [
        {
            "origin": origin,
            "destination": destination,
            "departure_date": departure_date,
        },
    ]
    offer_request = (
        client.offer_requests.create()
        .passengers([{"type": "adult"}])
        .slices(slices)
        .return_offers()
        .execute()
    )
    offers = offer_request.offers

    for idx, offer in enumerate(offers):
        print(
            f"{idx + 1}. {offer.owner.name} flight departing at "
            + f"{offer.slices[0].segments[0].departing_at} "
            + f"{offer.total_amount} {offer.total_currency}"
        )



destLabel = Label(root, text = "Where do want to go?")
destLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)
dest = Entry(root)
dest.grid(row=0,column=1)

srcLabel = Label(root, text = "From Where?")
srcLabel.grid(row=1,column=0)
src = Entry(root)
src.grid(row=1,column=1)

dateLabel = Label(root, text = "On what date? (YYYY-MM-DD)")
dateLabel.grid(row=2,column=0)
date = Entry(root)
date.grid(row=2,column=1)

submit = Button(root,text = "Submit",command= flightInfo)
submit.grid(row=3,column=0)


root.mainloop
```

Comment: Did you CALL the function?  And please do not include IMAGES of code or errors.  Cut-and-paste the code into your question.

Comment: I did, but why would that matter? I just want the tkinter window to open, regardless of whats in the function(not any tkinter related code). Regarding the image, my bad its my first time asking a question, I have added the actual text code :)

Comment: Why not show us the code that DOESN'T work?  You'd only have the screw up the indentation a little bit to confuse things.  If you indented everything starting at `destLabel`, for example, then of course there would be no window.

Comment: Again, I apologize. I have never used stackoverflow before so I am unfamiliar with the standards. I have edited the code again to show the code that does not work. Please let me know if there  are any other standards or syntaxes I messed up so I know for future. Ty

Comment: I believe the fix is brackets, so you have: root.mainloop()

Comment: @Oxin yeah, just tested it. It is simply missing the brackets. But I had to remove most of the logic as I didn't implement duffel_api. So there still might be a bug in it

Comment: @ovski, it was the brackets, tested it,  worked with the logic. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad my comment solved your problem (I've written it here as a formal answer for others to see if you want to upvote it).

The solution is that root.mainloop requires brackets, so it would look like:

> root.mainloop()

Answer (score 0):

Notice below that this minimal code will open a window.

If no window is opening, the code may be in an infinite loop.

I suggest starting adding widgets from the original code step by step to find the issue.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

It might even be better to start from this code.
This way, at least the program starts with one widget working.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="I Exist!")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```